# Oracle forms 11g get windows user login

Tags: windows, forms, oracle, web, oracle11g

how can I get the windows user login or Windows environment variables in Oracle Forms 11g of my Windows client (not from the application server)?

Sincerely
Chris

Comment: Not sure, I would guess your best bet is to look at the Oracle forms 11g JavaScript integration to see if that offers any way to do this. See this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e10240/javascript.htm .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need WebUtil functionality: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/webutil-090641.html

With WebUtil pll library you can e.g. get Windows client username like this:

```
client_win_api_environment.get_windows_username();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start your forms application with a batch file, and pass system environment parameters to the forms application URL.

e.g.
start.cmd:

```
iexplore.exe http://yourserver:1234/forms/servlet?config=yourconfig&windowsuser=%USERNAME%
```

after that you can just access the "GET" parameter windowsuser from within your forms fmb (don't forget to set up the forms parameter windowsuser)